# Pass object as props on Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do you go on passing objects as props on vue? I would imagine this would be a simple task but apparently not.

I have the following code on a .vue file:

```js
// register the child component
Vue.component('component', {
  props: {
    data: {
        type: Object
    }
  },
  template: '<div>Data: {{data}}</div>',
  mounted: function () {
    console.log(this.data)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="example">
    <component :data="msg"></component>
  </div>
<template/>
<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      msg:{}
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.msg = { x: 6}
  }
}
<script/>
```

Comment: Did you register the child component as component inside the parent? What error does the console show?

Comment: [`<component>`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) is a built-in component, maybe it's conflicting? Try naming it something else.

Comment: Yes, you should better not use built-in html elements but it works nevertheless: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/336271/

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? It is working https://jsfiddle.net/8moevz0w/2/, follow the same pattern for the vue.js file. For what I see, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to import axios in jsfiddle, but i can't get props object in axios inner  local file. 
http://jsfiddle.net/1pr3uqkh/1/

Comment: created -parent  ->  mounted -child  ->  mounted-parent  ->  created-axios-parent .______________

The result is that I console lifecycle hooks at component . when child component mounted ,then was parent component created-axios-parent .

Answer (score 0):

```
Vue.component('component', {
  props: {
    data: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({
          x: Number
        })
    }
  },
  template: '<div>Data: {{data.x}}</div>',
  mounted: function () {
    console.log(this.data)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

try this you use `x` but you never put default in it